# Font size not working with Docusign REST API in PHP

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with the Docusign REST API in PHP to send a signing documents. Everything is working fine except the font size of the text.

For font size of 32, I have tried something like

```
"font_size" => "size32",   but cannot get it to work.
```

How do I get the font size to work?

```
"textTabs"    => array(
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "Name",
        "value"     => "Nancy Moore",
"font_size" => "size64",
    )
),
"numberTabs"    => array(
    array(
        "tabLabel"  => "Contact",
        "value"     => "123456",
"font_size" => "size32",
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Curl Rest API**, the font size parameters differs from that **PHP SDK** of Docusign (font_size) hence the line of code below solve the issue.

```
"fontSize": "Size32",
```

Comment: Nancy, we in DocuSign would be interested to hear about what you're working on. If you want - please email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com and we can discuss

Comment: Thanks @Inbar for your help so far. We are working for a Client who wants Docusign to be integrated into his Humanitarian Application system. Am the youngest of the programming team. Thanks

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Would love to hear more when you got a chance. No rush.